# Controll Box is Always White in MetroFrameWork Windows Form

Tags: c#, designer, metroframework

I installed MetroFrameWork Package for Windows form And
When i Change the Theme to dark or white the Controll Box Does not change:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHU4s.jpg)

I reinstalled the package but it didn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Used The (Metro style Manager) and it changed thx,

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove control and add your own control boxes with code